# IF statement inside the CASE in P/L SQL

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I were trying write IF statement inside the CASE but that give me compile error. this my code look like

```
(CASE 
    IF (acc_type_id_ = 'ENDU') THEN
      WHEN PRODUCT_ID !=  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND PROD_ITEM_PKG.Get_Allow_Endu_Purch(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART'                               
      WHEN PRODUCT_ID =  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND SELL_ONLY_LINKED != 'YES' AND PROD_ITEM_PKG.Get_Allow_Endu_Purch(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART' 
    ELSE
       WHEN PRODUCT_ID !=  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART'                               
       WHEN PRODUCT_ID =  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND SELL_ONLY_LINKED != 'YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART' 
    END IF;   
ELSE '&ACTION_NO_ACTION'
END) ACTION2,
```

error in SQLPLUS

```
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Comment: Is this part of a procedure?

Answer (score 3):

What about this? You can use `acc_type_id_ = 'ENDU'` as part of `WHEN` condition to achieve same result.

```
(CASE 
      WHEN acc_type_id_ = 'ENDU' AND PRODUCT_ID !=  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND PROD_ITEM_PKG.Get_Allow_Endu_Purch(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART'                               
      WHEN acc_type_id_ = 'ENDU' AND PRODUCT_ID =  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND SELL_ONLY_LINKED != 'YES' AND PROD_ITEM_PKG.Get_Allow_Endu_Purch(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART' 
      WHEN acc_type_id_ != 'ENDU' AND PRODUCT_ID !=  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART'                               
      WHEN acc_type_id_ != 'ENDU' AND PRODUCT_ID =  product_id_ AND AVAIL_TO_SELL = 'YES' AND Enable_Add_To_Cart(PRODUCT_ID)='YES' AND SELL_ONLY_LINKED != 'YES' THEN '&ACTION_ADD_TO_CART' 
      ELSE '&ACTION_NO_ACTION'
END) ACTION2,
```